# Splitting with Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python, and I am trying to split a string using re.
I have researched a bit, and I have come across a few examples and I tried them out. They seem to work, but with limitation.

I am using a dictionary with a string key that is associated with an integer value. I'm trying to apply a weight to each word that depends on the integer value associated with the key string. My issue is that the string isn't formatted perfectly and I need to split it on underscores ( _ ) as well as whitespace and other various delimiters. From what I understand, this needs to be done with regular expressions. My bit of code is as follows:

```
for key, value in sorted_articles.items():
    wordList = print(re.split(r'(_|\s|:|)',key))
```

When I print this out, it splits everything fine, but it also prints out the delimiters rather than ignoring them in the list. For example, the string `"Hello_how are you_"` gets stored in the list as `['Hello', '_', 'how', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'you','_']`.
I'm not sure why the delimiters would be added to the list and I can't figure out how to fix it. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Use `r'[_\s:]'` or `r'(?:_|\s|:)'`. Once you add capturing groups into the pattern, those values will be part of the resulting list.

Comment: The first one worked perfectly, thank you! Would you be able to explain the latter solution, though? Just curious

Comment: Both are equivalent. They just split on `_`, whitespace and `:`.

Comment: Brackets do class matching. It matches with any character inside the brackets. No parenthesis does groupin g, beginning with ?: makes it non capture group, and pipes | are a or operator inside the group. So [abc] matches a or b or.  (ab|c) matches ab or c.

Answer (score 0):

You can split using the `\W+` character, which will split at all not alpha string items and use `|_` to specifically search for underscores:

```
for key, value in sorted_articles.items():
    wordList = print(re.split('\W+|_',key))
```

For instance:

```
s = "Hello_how are you_"

print(re.split("\W+|_", s))
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', '']
```